# triggers in pl/sql throw errors

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, triggers

What I need to do is I want to create a trigger which raises an error if both the proficiencies of the programmer are equal. Please tell me the errors I have done.

```
SQL> get f:/sqlprog/trigger_3;
  1  create or replace trigger t2 before insert or update on programmer for          each
 row
  2  declare
  3  cursor c1 is select prof1, prof2 from programmer;
  4  begin
  5  for r1 in c1 loop
  6  if r1.pname=:new.pname then
  7  if :new.prof1=: new.prof2 then
  8  raise_application_error(-20091,'prof1 and prof2 should not be same');
  9  end if;
  10  end if;
   11  end loop;
  12* end;
 SQL> /
```

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

```
 SQL> show errors
 Errors for TRIGGER T2:

 LINE/COL ERROR
 -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
 4/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the
          following:
          constant exception <an identifier>
          <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
          char time timestamp interval date binary national character
          nchar

 6/15     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ":" when expecting one of the
          following:
          ( - + all case mod new null <an identifier>
          <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>

 LINE/COL ERROR
 -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
         continue any avg count current max min prior some sql stddev
         sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
         date <a string literal with character set specification>
         <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
         <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set
         specification>
         <an alternative
```

these are the errors which i encountered and the table regarding programmer is given below 
prof1=proficieny 1
prof2= proficieny 2

```
 SQL> desc programmer;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 PNAME                                              VARCHAR2(20)
 DOB                                                DATE
 DOJ                                                DATE
 SEX                                                CHAR(1)
 PROF1                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 PROF2                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 SALARY                                             NUMBER(5)
```

I don't have any idea why I am getting them please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  My guess is that you want a `check` constraint rather than a trigger.  If you want to be inefficient and have a trigger rather than a constraint, I'm guessing that you just want to check `if :new.prof1 = :new.prof2` and get rid of the loop and the first if statement.

Comment: sir  i am new to this and i am a slow learner could you pls be some more precise of what i should do ?

Comment: First, explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm trying to guess based on what I think you think your code might do.  But it's entirely possible that my guess is wrong.  Why are you using a trigger?  Why do you have two proficiency columns in the table rather than a one to many mapping table?  Does every programmer really have exactly two proficiencies?  No one has 1 or 3?

Comment: as you said one can use check constraint but our sir told us to do with triggers only even though we can do it as you said . he told in such a way because for practice . 

programmers may have many proficiencies but he(our sir) ended up giving us only two columns and he made this question for us to solve.

what i am trying to do is to raise an error when the two columns of any inserted record have same values in the columns prof1 and prof2.

pls once look at the question sir i have edited some . this is my first quesiton in stackoverflow so pls bear with my  mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the cursor, lose the loop, and get rid of the first `if` statement.  Only the innermost `if` statement makes sense

```
create or replace trigger t2 
  before insert or update on programmer 
  for each row
begin
  if :new.prof1 = :new.prof2 
  then
   raise_application_error(-20091,'prof1 and prof2 should not be same');
  end if;
end;
```

In a row-level trigger, you generally cannot query the table that the trigger is defined on.  You can only make decisions based on the data in the `:new` and `:old` pseudo-records.

Comment: could you pls give me your gmail id sir i will directly mail to you if there are any doubts and give me  only if you are comfortable with this

Comment: could you pls tell  me any nice reference for this subject sir